# Why the need for quotes in the change of extension bash commands? It seems to work fine without quotes

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to change extension of .pdf file to .zip

both commands given below  gave me results

```
for i in *.pdf; do mv $i ${i%.pdf}.zip;  done
```

or

```
for i in *.pdf; do mv "$i" "${i%.pdf}.zip";  done
```

What is purpose `" "` in this command

Comment: The first version won't work if any of the filenames contain whitespace.

Comment: Here is another simple solution: `rename '.pdf' '.zip' *.pdf`